# Parameterized field names in Groovy Sql

Tags: sql, groovy, parameterized-query

I have a small tool that does a few simple operations on a database.  It puts together SQL queries based on configuration (including field names) passed into it by running `toString` on `GString`s.  Recently I've been trying to move off of `GString` and use the more secure parameterized query feature.  The problem is that my configurable field names do not seem to work.  Consider this code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

Sql.withInstance('jdbc:comdb2://dev/brpcfgdb?comdb2dbname=comdb3db') { Sql sql ->
    sql.rows('SELECT * FROM docs WHERE :sourceFld IS :source', [sourceFld: 'source', source: 'www']).forEach { row ->
        println row
    }

    println "----------"

    sql.rows('SELECT * FROM docs WHERE source IS :source', [source: 'www']).forEach { row ->
        println row
    }
}
```

I'd expect the exact same rows to be printed above and below the dashed line.  Instead, no rows are printed before, and the expected number are printed below.

**Is it possible to specify field names in a parameterized query?** Or am I stuck with concatenations and/or `GString`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's impossible to pass parametrized table & column names - jdbc drivers does not support this.

possible to build sql dynamically but potentially it leads to sql injection vulnerability.

you could do it through this code:

```
def sourceFld = 'surce'
sql.rows('SELECT * FROM docs WHERE ${sourceFld} IS :sourceVal', [sourceVal: 'www']).forEach { row ->
    println row
}
```

or

```
Map params = [
    source: 'www'
]
String query = 'SELECT * FROM docs WHERE ' + params.collect{k,v-> "$k = :$k" }.join(' AND ')
sql.rows(query,params).forEach { row ->
    println row
}
```

Comment: For my use-case the first one works.  Column names never come from the end-user and are configured ahead of time.